# Presentations sharing webapp that works without Flash

Tags: web-apps, presentation

I want to upload a presentation to share it with the public, but I don't want to install [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player).

On [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/), upload does not complete correctly if Flash is not installed.

Requirements:

- Can upload and view presentations using HTML only. No Flash required.
- Free to upload.
- Accepts [ODP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Document_Format).
- Can be viewed by anyone without registration.
- Not too long (less than 100 characters?), trustworthy-looking URL. For instance `presentations.com/nicolas-raoul/future-of-cmis` or `http://slides.net/213122` is OK, but `goo.gl/iu2r3vc` is not OK because people can't imagine what is behind, Google Drive is not OK because of the long opaque URLs.
- No or little advertisement.

Great to have:

- Visible on mobile by normal web browsers, no need to install an app.

Comment: On the URL length front, I suggest a URL shortener. I generally hate the things, but if you are afraid of big long URLs, you probably need one.

Comment: @MichaelKohne: By "trustworthy" I mean that people will hesitate to click on `goo.gl/iu2r3vc` because it can redirect them to anything, people will prefer a link like `presentations.com/nicolas-raoul/future-of-cmis` because they can see what it is about.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul *technically* that url could just as easily be setup to redirect them to anywhere but I do see that possibly some users of limited knowledge that won't enter their minds - however most people with limited knowledge don't even look at the urls they are going to in my tech support experience. Also How long are you considering *Short*?

Comment: I take it "Upload the presentation to Google Drive" and use Google Doc's presentation viewer isn't an option due to the URL issue?

Comment: @aendrew: Yes, unfortunately